# symfony, pager and unescape one of values instead of all of them

Tags: symfony1, pager

I want to display raw data of one value from database. Table is quite big, with a lot of data and i need only 5 columns on index page. So i defined needed columns in criteria and used doSelectStmt with pager to paginate result.

Im displaying it like this:

http://pastebin.com/bccSkjs1

TEXT field contains some HTML and i want to display it normally (not escaped). However, 3 other fields (not show in code above) **have to** be escaped, because they can have some html too, but it cannot by interpreted as html.

I know that in normal object, i can do: `$sf_data->getRaw("foo")->getBar()` instead of `$foo->getBar()` to get expected result.

But how i can get same, when i dont have normal object, only array of data like in this case?

I know i can do `$sf_data->getRaw("pager")->getResults()` in a foreach, but it will unescape ALL fields which is tottal wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to access the properties via arrays (which is ugly btw)?

If you were accessing the properties via the object getter methods, you could do:

```
echo $News->getText(ESC_RAW);
```

And your `text` field would be escaped.

Comment: well, yes, i have to use it in this way.